# remove element with attribute php

Tags: php, attributes

I have a lot of elements with the same starting but I want to remove the ones that have the `style` attribute:

[Example A]

```
<table style="display:none;" name="56de9e1ee43fb"><tr width="30px"><td>blah blah blah</td></tr></table>
```

but as it has the attribute of `style` I want it to be

[Example B]

```
<!--Nothing-->
```

Is there any way of doing this in PHP???

And can you make it so you can get rid of the elements inside of it also???

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with a DOM Parser for php, like DOMDocument. 
See the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) about this parser.